# Regex to match static keyword and variables

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a more concise way to capture keywords from a string using Perl flavor of regex.

An example string is:

```
QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem INTER in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
```

I need to capture the keyword (with the forward slashes):

```
/QSECOFR/
```

And the following potential variables after the word **subsystem**

```
INTER
QINTER
QINTER2
QCTL
```

I have the following regex, but looking for a more compact way of checking this:

```
/\/QSECOFR\/\w+\s\w+\s+\w+\s\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\w+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\sin\ssubsystem\s(?:QINTER|QINTER2|INTER|QCTL)\sin\sQSYS/
```

This tests fine here: https://regex101.com/r/eSyRVZ/1

But something a little less over-engineered would be preferred.

Thanks!

Edit:

To help make it clearer, I'm hoping for the regex that will match any of the following:

```
 QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem INTER in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)

QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QINTER in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)

QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QINTER2 in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)

QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QCTL in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
```

Comment: Your regex does not _capture_ anything -- to capture you need to use `()`. Your regex just looks at some pattern and as not any code provided it is not obvious what you do with the string if it matches.

Comment: Are you using "perl compatible regex" or an actual Perl application? PCRE would be better referred to as "perl inspired regex" so it's important to know which your question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out in the end, this worked:

```
/.*\/QSECOFR\/.*(?:QINTER|QINTER2|ABCINTER|QSYS).*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not include specific on what you want to capture from log file, in original post you just match regex against a string without capturing anything.

Perhaps the code should look like the following piece

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

while( <DATA> ) {
 say $1 if m!(/QSECOFR/.*?subsystem\s+(INTER|QINTER|QINTER2|QCTL).*?)\.!;
}

__DATA__
QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem INTER in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QINTER in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QINTER2 in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QCTL in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
QSECOFR Logins: (Information / 00) Job 874194/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem ACTL in QSYS. Job entered system on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13. (at 2020-01-09 14:06:13)
```

Output

```
/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem INTER in QSYS
/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QINTER in QSYS
/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QINTER2 in QSYS
/QSECOFR/ABC1E started on 09/01/20 at 14:06:13 in subsystem QCTL in QSYS
```

Comment: Regex can be simplified even further to following form `say $1 if m!(/QSECOFR/.*?(INTER|QINTER|QINTER2|QCTL).*?)\.!;` if you want less _readable_ version (word subsystem is omitted).